# Heap in Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

can someone explain whats the importance of ***HeapDesc* in ShaneSaunders Dijkstra algorithm** and how it is used here? 
In general i know how Dijkstra algorithm works. But, i din't get the heap part in implementation.

Its a big code. hence am posting a link if u want to have a look at it.

Here go's http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/research/RG/alg/dijkstra.cpp

Comment: What part are you unclear about? The definition of the HeapDesc or how it's used?

Answer (score 1):

In Dijkstra you need an efficient data structure that provides you with the edge of minimum cost that allows you to reach another vertex.

[Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is exactly a data structure that allows you to store the set of edges and efficiently retrieve the one with minimum cost.

Comment: I may change *"the data structure"* for *"a data structure"* though

Answer (score 1):

HeapDesc probably implements the factory design pattern to create different kinds of Heaps. If you check the file http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/research/RG/alg/dijkstra.h, you will notice that the heap variable in the constructor is an object of type Heap.

Take a look on this article for the factory design pattern.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 0):

[Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) involves a lot of "path of the lowest cost"  lookup.

Min or max lookup is what a [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is optimized for ( O(1) ), and this is why it is used.

As to `HeapDesc` itself, it just appears to be [a factory method](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/research/RG/alg/heap.h), used to allocate a Heap object.

```
Heap *newInstance(int n) const { return new T(n); }; // from heap.h
```

Comment: But, what does this represents here in his code.
heap = heapDD->newInstance(nn);
and how he defined it

Comment: @NRK I am not sure what `HeapDesc` itself is, but it looks like an allocator or factory method used to create a heap. You would need to look into "heaps/heap.h" for it.